# jqgrid add row without url instead call a javascript function on popup submit

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I am displaying data using jqgrid, I have used jqgrid('navgrid', '#pager', {add:true. edit:true, delete:true}...
Screen displays different icons on screen top left (for add, edit, delete)
Instead of using URL, I want to call a function on submit button of popup, do some manipulations on data and then make an ajax call.

I tried to search for this over internet, but could not find a solution.

Thanks,
Shivey

Comment: why you try to use ajax call...  what are you trying.. give some more details

Comment: Actually, Instead of using a DB I am updating an XML file in the back-end, so on edit/edit/delete, instead of adding elements I am replacing the whole file with a new one. If a row is added, I want to add that record to jqgrid array and send it so that my JAXB code can marshal it... I suppose this gives you some insight of what I am doing...